# Modal Video React props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, components

I'm using this react modal video component https://appleple.github.io/react-modal-video/ but the props videoId={this.props.video} doesn't work, can you explain me why?. The code I used is:

```
class Video extends React.Component {

constructor () {
  super()
  this.state = {
    isOpen: false
  }
  this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this)
}

openModal () {
  this.setState({isOpen: true})
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      <ModalVideo channel='youtube' isOpen={this.state.isOpen} videoId={this.props.spotlight} onClose={() => this.setState({isOpen: false})} />
      <div className="SpotlightButton">
      <button onClick={this.openModal}>Open</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}} export default Video
```

Comment: Could you share the code where you are using the component?

Comment: @stef this one? ` <Group>
            <Name>{props.name}</Name>
            <Surname>{props.surname}</Surname>
            <Descritpion>{props.description}</Descritpion>
            <video></video>
        </Group>) `
and then `<Group
        name="" 
         ...
          videoId="">
    </Group>`

Comment: I think @stef means you need to include the code where you are calling the <Video /> component to see what are you passing as `spotlight`